# error: " type object 'world_load' has no attribute 'split' "

Tags: python

i try to make a game BUT I can not get the world load to work
fings that cud be gud to no
the var update is for the while loop
the error is in the area wer the block gets pikt and displayd.

```
class world_load:
def __init__(self, line):
    self.type = line[0]
    self.x = line[1]
    self.y = line[2]
def __str__(self):
    return self.type+" "+self.x+" "+self.y


with open(fillName, encoding=encoding) as file:
    file.readline()
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(" ")
        w = world_load(line)
        world.append(p)

 while update:

#input

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:


       update = False 




dis.fill(sky)


for world_load in world:

    wo = world_load.split(" ")

    if wo[0] == block_grass:

        block_grass(wo[1],wo[2])
```

it's wos not the hole code
hear is the error fing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Deltagare\Desktop\program\Game\Game.py", line 68, in <module>
wo = world_load.split(" ")
AttributeError: type object 'world_load' has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is very hard to read your question because you have used poor grammar and spelling. secondly the `.split()` function in python is used for strings to split them into an array (list). You might be attempting to split your own class which is not a string and will not work. Or you could be attempting to call the split function within your class (This is what Python thinks you are trying to do) and will also not work because there is no split function. It is unclear what you are asking. I advise you rewrite this question to a higher standard and then people will be more able to help.